# MySQL join not working even after many attempts in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am sure I might be doing small mistake but I am not able to catch the error. I am unable to understand why I am not able to use a join query in MySQL.

I have three relational tables in DB:

1. class
2. subject
3. class_subject

Code is:

```
   CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `class` (
  `ClassID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Class` VARCHAR(500)  NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `Section` VARCHAR(500)  NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClassID`))

ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 15
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


INSERT INTO `class`(`ClassID`, `Class`, `Section`) VALUES ('1','1','A'), ('2','1','B'), ('3','1','C'), ('4','1','D') ;

    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Subject` (
  `SubjectID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Subject` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`SubjectID`))


ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 53
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

INSERT INTO `Subject`(`SubjectID`, `Subject`) VALUES ('1','English'),('2','Hindi'),('3','Maths'),('4','Science'),('5','Social Science'),('6','Sports'),('7','Physics'), ('8','Chemistry'), ('9','Statistics'), ('10','Computers');
```

and...

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `class_subject` (
ClassID INT (11) NOT NULL,  
SubjectID INT (11) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (ClassID, SubjectID),  
INDEX `subject_order_idx` (`ClassID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `class_subject`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ClassID` )
  REFERENCES `class` (`ClassID` )ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`SubjectID` )
  REFERENCES `subject` (`SubjectID` )ON UPDATE CASCADE)

ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 15
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


INSERT INTO `class_subject`(`ClassID`, `SubjectID`) VALUES ('1','1'), ('1','2'), ('1','3'), ('12','4'), ('12','5'), ('12','6');
```

Join query:

```
$ClassID = "1";
$sql =  "SELECT subject.SubjectID, subject.Subject FROM subject " .
        "LEFT JOIN class_subject" .
        "ON subject.SubjectID = class_subject.SubjectID " .
        "WHERE class_subject.ClassID = $ClassID " .
        "ORDER BY SubjectID ASC";
```

Although same query is working fine in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: What is your question? Where is the `JOIN` that isn't working? There's no such thing as a `PHP join`, join is part of SQL, not PHP.

Comment: Hi Barmar...I was n process of posting the query here thats why you have seen incomplete post. Anyways I ahve completed the same now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a space at the end of this string:

```
"LEFT JOIN class_subject " .
```

If you'd done `echo $sql` you would have seen that it said:

```
LEFT JOIN class_subjectON
```

Errors like this are why I don't recommend you write strings like that. Just write the string with newlines in it:

```
$sql =  "SELECT subject.SubjectID, subject.Subject FROM subject
         LEFT JOIN class_subject
         ON subject.SubjectID = class_subject.SubjectID
         WHERE class_subject.ClassID = $ClassID
         ORDER BY SubjectID ASC";
```

PHP allows newlines in string literals, and so does SQL, so there's no need for the concatenation.

Comment: Corrected voted up.. :) very fast I didn't have time to do it by the time I read it you had it posted :) hehe

Comment: @user2677125 I hope you've learned the most important debugging technique: echo your query to see if it contains what you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

You need a space at the end of the second line:

```
$sql =  "SELECT subject.SubjectID, subject.Subject FROM subject " .
        "LEFT JOIN class_subject " .
--------------------------------^
        "ON subject.SubjectID = class_subject.SubjectID " .
        "WHERE class_subject.ClassID = $ClassID " .
        "ORDER BY SubjectID ASC";
```

Answer (score 1):

@`Barmar` nails the issue on the head, but I wanted to post a small variation on the missing space issue using a formatting technique I like to use for PHP & MySQL stuff like this:

```
$ClassID = "1";
$sql = "SELECT subject.SubjectID, subject.Subject"
     . " FROM subject"
     . " LEFT JOIN class_subject ON subject.SubjectID = class_subject.SubjectID"
     . " WHERE class_subject.ClassID = $ClassID"
     . " ORDER BY SubjectID ASC"
     ;
```

The basic concept of this formatting can be condensed into three items:

- Each MySQL instruction has it’s own line. In this case `SELECT`, `FROM`, `LEFT JOIN`, `WHERE` & `ORDER BY` are each on one line. The benefit is readability. But also you can quickly & easily comment out one or more lines without having to radically rewrite your query while developing.
- Place the concatenation `.` to the left of the line. The right side really can be forgotten or missed if you normally read from left to right.
- The space between MySQL instructions happens on the left of each line. Same logic as above.

Follow a formatting structure like this & you will make your debugging life tons easier. And it makes it easier for others to read when they assist you.

Comment: Still prefer formatting with newlines and a unique string as it allows you to basically copy / paste a request and only have to replace variables.